# To find the winner of tic-tac-toe for 4 consecutive values instead of three in given tuple of tuple using python

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to write a function that displays who is the winner in the game of tic tac toe for **4** consecutive values. If X is the winner it returns X, If O is the winner it returns O and for a draw, it returns boolean None What I tried works for some cases and fails for test cases given below Please help .
**This is similar to tic-tac-toe except instead of 3 consecutive 'X' or 'O' there must be 4 consecutive X or O's in a row or column or diagonally.**
I've tried searching the web it is giving me results with `itertools`, `any` and `numpy` which I do not understand.
Following is the code for 3 dimensional which works although as I am learning python I am unsure how to find consecutive items in a list.

```
def check_winner(tuples):
    for line in range(3):
        print(line)
        #check for row win
        if tuples[line][0] == tuples[line][1] == tuples[line][2]:
            # print("1 ")
            return tuples[line][0];
        #check for col win
        if tuples[0][line] == tuples[1][line] == tuples[2][line]:
            # print("2")
            return tuples[0][line];
    # For diagonal
    if tuples[0][0] == tuples[1][1] == tuples[2][2]:
        return tuples[0][0]
    if tuples[0][2] == tuples[1][1] == tuples[2][0]:
        return tuples[2][0]
```

Following are test cases:

```
xwins = ((None, None, None, None, None, None, None),
         (None, None, None, None, None, None, None),
         (None, None, None, None, "X" , None, None),
         (None, None, None, "X" , "O" , "O", None),
         (None, "O" , "X" , "X" , "O" , "X", None),
         ("O" , "X" , "O" , "O" , "O" , "X" , "X"))
owins = ((None, None, None, None, None, None, None),
         (None, None, None, None, None, None, None),
         ("O" , "O" , "O" , "O" , None, None, None),
         ("O" , "X" , "X" , "X" , None, None, None),
         ("X" , "X" , "X" , "O" , "X" , None, None),
         ("X" , "O" , "O" , "X" , "O" , None, None))
nowins =(("X" , "X" , None, None, None, None, None),
         ("O" , "O" , None, None, None, None, None),
         ("O" , "X" , "O" , "O" , None, "O" , "O" ),
         ("O" , "X" , "X" , "X" , None, "X" , "X" ),
         ("X" , "X" , "X" , "O" , "X" , "X" , "O" ),
         ("X" , "O" , "O" , "X" , "O" , "X" , "O" ))
xwins2 = ((None, None, None, None, None, None, None),
         ("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"),
         (None, None, None, None, "X" , None, None),
         (None, None, None, "X" , "O" , "O", None),
         (None, "O" , "X" , "X" , "O" , "X", None),
         ("O" , "X" , "O" , "O" , "O" , "X" , "X"))
```

The above code works perfectly for 3 consecutive values but for the above test cases I am not able to figure out the logic as I am not aware of an easier method to find the consecutive values in a list or a tuple

Comment: Is the size of the board always 6x7?

Comment: @trincot yes the size remains 6 X 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using a regular expression. Turn your board into a string where rows are delimited by a character (not "X" or "O"), and None is also mapped to such a character.

Then it is a matter of finding a pattern:

```
import re

def check_winner(tuples):
    s = "|".join(["".join([c or "." for c in row]) for row in tuples])
    res = re.findall(r"([XO])(\1{3}|(.{5}\1){3}|(.{6}\1){3}|(.{7}\1){3})", s)
    if res:
        return res[0][0]
```

If you are looking to do this with looping and comparing the played values explicitly, then make sure that you test whether the value is not `None`, as a four-in-a-row of only `None` values should of course not stop the search for a winner. You could do it like this:

```
def check_winner(tuples):
    # Check for horizontal winners
    for row in tuples:
        for x in range(len(row) - 3):
            if row[x] and row[x] == row[x+1] == row[x+2] == row[x+3]:
                return row[x]
    
    # Check for vertical winners
    for x in range(len(tuples)):
        for y in range(len(tuples) - 3):
            if tuples[y][x] and tuples[y][x] == tuples[y+1][x] == tuples[y+2][x] == tuples[y+3][x]:
                return tuples[y][x]

    # Check for diagonal winners
    for x in range(len(tuples) - 3):
        for y in range(len(tuples) - 3):
            if tuples[y][x] and tuples[y][x] == tuples[y+1][x+1] == tuples[y+2][x+2] == tuples[y+3][x+3]:
                return tuples[y][x]
            if tuples[y+3][x] and tuples[y+3][x] == tuples[y+2][x+1] == tuples[y+1][x+2] == tuples[y][x+3]:
                return tuples[y+3][x]
```

Comment: The code works perfectly fine. But I am looking for a simpler basic approach where I could understand the logic as I am just 2 months learning my first programming language. Thanks for the help though I am definitely going to start learning `regex` as soon as possible

Comment: Added a more traditional solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do in order to simplify your problem is just check the most recently placed X or O since you know from the previous round that the other X's and and O's aren't enough to win (otherwise the game would be over). So for the most recently placed symbol you will get some coordinates (x,y) you just need to check how many you find in the same line. For example for the horizontal line you could do:

```
# tuples[x][y] is the symbol we are looking at
x_min = x
x_max = x

# now we check to the left how many symbols we find that are the same
while 0 < x_min:
    if tuples[x_min-1][y] == tuples[x][y]:
        x_min -= 1
    else:
        break

# now we look how far to the right we can go
# here x_bound is the maximum value x can be which in your test cases would be 6
while x_bound > x_max:
    if tuples[x_max+1][y] == tuples[x][y]:
        x_max += 1
    else:
        break

# now we know the indexes of the left and rightmost symbol that is the same as tuples[x][y]
# and we can just calculate how many there are in between
adjacent = x_max - x_min + 1

return adjacent >= 4
```

I know this isn't the most elegant solution but it is pretty easy to understand so I hope it can help you out since you can apply pretty much the same method for the vertical lines just do it for `y` but for the diagonal lines you need to do it for both at the same time.

if my assumption is incorrect and you don't know which symbol was placed last you can just run this code for every X and O on the board until you find the winner (and if you can't it is a tie)

Comment: It doesn't really help me! I am looking for a simpler way to find if a tuple or a list consist certain value consecutively. Thanks for the effort though. Appreciate it!